# I want to change component when a link is clicked

Tags: reactjs, navigation, components

I want to change different component when a link is clicked. Like when I clicked forget password then forget password component should be open.

I used router and switch to change my component but is not working. It will add the content of new component on the current component.

```
<Form>
              <h1>LOGIN</h1>
              <div className="form-content" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                  <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>
                <Router>
                  <Link to='/Forgetpassword'>Forget Password</Link>

                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/Forgetpassword" Component={Forgetpassword} />
                    {/* </Route> */}
                  </Switch>
                </Router>
                <div className="btn-content">
                  <Button variant="primary">
                    Signup
              </Button>
                  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
              </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Form>
```

Comment: i posted example that will help you if go through once https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504851/6544460

Comment: hey check that i posted simple solution of requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504851/6544460

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pradeep  and welcome to stack-overflow community :)

react-router path should be equal to a route, for instance: /login
then the component attribute should be equal to a component so for example when the user navigate to /login he would see the login page.

same example can be used for forget password page.

check this live example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

good luck !

Comment: thanks i did from the same reference you share but its load the content of new component to the current component

Comment: @Pradeep I can help you further with your code if you share it.

Comment: Try to add the 'exact' keyword in the Route component like so: `<Route exact path="/component" Component={component}/>`

Comment: @NateBen i edited my previous code above, please have a look !

Comment: hey @Pradeep , I can see what the problem is, checkout this pen with a suggested solution for it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fipmdy

Comment: @Pradeep you have to extract the ` <Router>` component out of where it is now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you that how to work with routing and 
for clarification just go through documentation of [react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}


function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      Visit <Link to="/about">----> About</Link>
      <p>You landed to Home page</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function About(){
  return(
        <div>
         <h2>About</h2>
          Visit <Link to="/">----> Home</Link>
          <p>You landed to about page</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```